# Spark can't read content of a table

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I had a managed hive table and moved it to a different database using the following command:

```
alter table_name rename to new_db.table_name
```

The table was successfully moved and all the data is under the database now. The table is shown fine in HIVE. However when I try to read the table from Spark, it can read the schema but there is no content in there. That is, the `count` returns zero! What has happened? How can I fix this issue?

I loading it in spark using the following code:

```
val t = sqlContext.table("new_db.table_name")
```

Comment: can you add your spark code?

Comment: I did that. There should not be anything wrong with it cause this is how I always load tables from HIVE into spark

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes just altering the name isn't enough, I had to also alter the location.

```
sqlContext.sql("""
ALTER TABLE new_table 
SET LOCATION "hdfs://.../new_location"
""")
```

And refresh the table in Spark for good measure

```
sqlContext.sql("""
REFRESH TABLE new_table 
""")
```

You can double-check if the location is correct w/ `describe formatted new_table`